# change version of app when updating on google developer

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my app on google developer market, and I decided to update the app because I made some changes on it, but it gives this error message:

> Upload failed
>
> You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.

how can I change the version of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open manifest and 
do this

**android:versionCode="2"**

**android:versionName="1.1"****

Answer (score 1):

this is set up either in your build.gradle file or in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Change your Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.xxx"
android:versionCode="8"
android:versionName="xxx-xxxxx-2-v1" >
```

Here VersionCode you have to change.